# Define a custom url in admin area

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I'm having troubles in defining a new custom url in admin area.

Here is my routes.xml file, saved in /app/code/Vendor/Module/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="unlock">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Then I've created a custom button in the cart rule edit page

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\SalesRule\Edit\Button;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic;
class Unlock extends Generic
{
    protected $request;
    protected $urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
       $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
       }


    public function getUnlockUrl($id)
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('*/*/unlock', ['id' => $id]);
    }

    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $id = (int)$this->request->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            return [
                'label' => __('Unlock'),
                'on_click' =>  'deleteConfirm(' . json_encode(__('Are you sure you want to Unlock?'))
                    . ','
                    . json_encode($this->getUnlockUrl($id))
                    . ')',
                'sort_order' => 100
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Button works, but when I click it Magento redirects to a 404 page. What is the correct url, giving the above code?
Do I making mistakes in using the getUrl() method?

Comment: what is a controller path for this delete URL?

Comment: app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Unlock.php

Comment: Can you please try this url and see it is working or not
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('unlock/index/unlock', ['id' => $id]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

routes.xml file in /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright © BrainActs Commerce OÜ. All rights reserved.
  ~ See LICENSE.txt for license details.
  -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="unlock" frontName="unlock">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

updated **Unlock.php** file Code

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\SalesRule\Edit\Button;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic;
class Unlock extends Generic
{
    protected $request;
    protected $urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
       $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
       }


    public function getUnlockUrl($id)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('unlock/index/unlock');
    }

    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $id = (int)$this->request->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            return [
                'label' => __('Unlock'),
                'on_click' =>  'deleteConfirm(' . json_encode(__('Are you sure you want to Unlock?'))
                    . ','
                    . json_encode($this->getUnlockUrl($id))
                    . ')',
                'sort_order' => 100
            ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry but I've not understood... giving mine/your code, what the final url will be?

Comment: now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
For Admin Route

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="admin">
            <route id="unlock" frontName="unlock">
                <module name="Vendor_Module" />
            </route>
        </router>
    </config>
```

For Button

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\SalesRule\Edit\Button;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic;
class Unlock extends Generic
{
    protected $request;
    protected $urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
       $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
       }


    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $id = (int)$this->request->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            return [
                'label' => __('Unlock'),
                'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . __(
                        'Are you sure you want to do this?'
                    ) . '\', \'' . $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('*/*/unlock', ['id' => $ruleId]) . '\')',
                'sort_order' => 100
            ];
        }
    }
}
```